# Different NuGet Web.Config.Transforms for Different MVC Versions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, powershell, .net-4.0, nuget

I'm creating a nuget package that I want to be compatible for both MVC2 and MVC3 applications (all on .net 4.0).

The problem is, I want to add some namespaces to the web.config file (like so):

```
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="NewPackage.Web" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

But for razor, I'd have to put it in as such:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages>
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="NewPackage.Web" />
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

But of course, this wouldn't work for MVC2. So I was hoping for some way to conditionally run a web.config.transform only if mvc3 is detected. I understand nuget doesn't really have the capability to do this but I was wondering about powershell. I know you can create an install.ps1 and I know it can detect a project's references but can it detect a reference version number and then run a web.config.transform? Is there some better way?

I know I could create a new package following a pattern like `NewPackage.Mvc3`, like I've seen others do but that doesn't seem very obvious to a user installing it and I only want a slightly different `web.config.transform` so that's my fallback option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe what your describing is possible using the default transform support. You might be able to invoke the transform feature directly from a powershell install script, otherwise you'll have to make the changes manually (and roll them back on your uninstall script).

Comment: As I figured. I'm hoping for a clue as to how to invoke the transform feature from powershell (if that's even possible) or some alternative I've yet to find/think.

Comment: I'd recommend asking a separate question on the subject and also asking on the [NuGet project discussion area](http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions)